# The General Idea Behind Google Game Services Turn-Based Matchmaking

Tags: google-play-services, matchmaking

I am just starting to develop a Turn-Based game with the Google Play Game Services, and I am utterly confused about the steps to initiate the match.

My game has a maximum of 2 players at once, and I am using the default UI for match-making.

How can I actually wait for the another player to join? My game currently "starts", even with only the local player.. meaning: Why is the "match initiated callback" invoked, even if no another player has even joined the game? What event is invoked when another player joins the game, so I can possibly display a "waiting for another player" UI? Should I have a need for such an UI? I have this nagging feeling that I am misunderstanding something essential here.